# Using RSA signature with wso2esb

Tags: rsa, wso2-esb

I was trying to deploy 1 war file in WSO2AS which contains a call to REST api and use SHA private key for authentication and got the following error

The error is at line::Delete.java:118
Signature.getinstance("RSA");

in java code.
I have added the bouncy castle jars in AS library but still getting the error.
Thanks in advance !!

caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA Signature not available
        at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:224)
        at chef.Delete.Delete(Delete.java:118)